# How to compare the elements of a SortedSet to see how many elements of the two sets match

Tags: java, hashcode, sortedset

I'm writing a program that tests lottery pick programs for statistical analysis. I pretty much have an idea of how to store the data. My question is: how I can take two sortedsets of equal size (I have a method that checks that), compare them and return a number that represents the number of matching elements in both sets?

I can post my code, but really I have no idea what method to use. I want to know what way I'm going to solve this before I code too much. Should I use the hashcode method or some other way to attack this issue?

Comment: `setOne.retainAll(setTwo).size()`?

Comment: How a set could be sorted? it's an unsorted and unordered collection by definition

Comment: Like this!
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(s1); 
intersection.retainAll(s2);
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Do both sets have to be hashsets or can one be a treeset and one be a hashset?

Comment: @user3113314 My friend both should be hashset but SortedSet also have retainAll method u can chk http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Comment: The implementing type of the `Set` interface does not matter as long as one of them implements the `retainAll` method and that implementation is the one on which you call the `retainAll` method.

Comment: @DwB you are right my friend all are implementing the set

Comment: @user3113314 so you got that, then mark it as correct